# Uncaught ReferenceError, my function is not defned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a dyanamic scrolling div and it works fine on Jsfiddle as seen here --> http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/19/embedded/result/ yet on the browser I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onscroll' of null

So then I added `$(document).ready(function (){` to my code and got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: yHandler is not defined

I'm not understanding why I'm getting these errors yet its flowing smoothly on jsfiddle. I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm not understanding or missing. Code in question is below

```
var movelist = document.getElementById('movelist');
    $(document).ready(function (){
    function  yHandler (){
        var contentHeight = movelist.scrollHeight;
        var yOffset = movelist.clientHeight;
        var y = yOffset + movelist.scrollTop;
        if(y >= contentHeight){
            movelist.innerHTML += '<div class ="newData">hey look at me</div>';
        }
    }
});
movelist.onscroll = yHandler;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working in your Fiddle because everything is in the same scope.  You are declaring `movelist` outside your `$(document).ready`.  Move both the `var movielist = ...` and `movielist.onscroll = yHandler;` inside your `$(document).ready`.

You can also move your `yHandler` function outside your `$(document).ready`.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation the errors stopped. So why isn't my div not being fired now? @Gromer

Comment: @Octavius what you mean by "my div is not being fired"?

Comment: When I scroll <div class ="newData">hey look at me</div> is not showing when I scroll like it is here --> http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/21/

Comment: @Octavius, I'm assuming you mean the code inside `if(y >= contentHeight)` isn't being called?  Or your `yHandler` in general?  In either case, I would set a break point in the various javascript consoles of Chrome/Firefox/IE to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
var movelist = document.getElementById('movelist');
```

and

```
movelist.onscroll = yHandler;
```

inside your document.ready call.

Or, get rid of the document.ready call (you don't seem to have any jQuery in there anyway) and put your code in a script block at the end of your document before the closing body tag.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9zXL5/20/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function outside the tag  `$(document).ready(function (){...});`

Comment: This would work, but it's not the right way, since it's creating globals, you should move everything within the `ready` function

Comment: You right, it is not a good habit to define functions outsite the .ready() method

Comment: Actually, there are lots of functions that need to be global. However, if a function doesn't need to be global, then it shouldn't, which is the case here

Answer (score 0):

You should move all your code to within the onload handler

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var movelist = document.getElementById('movelist');
    function  yHandler (){  
        var contentHeight = movelist.scrollHeight;
        var yOffset = movelist.clientHeight;
        var y = yOffset + movelist.scrollTop;

        if(y >= contentHeight){
            movelist.innerHTML += '<div class ="newData">hey look at me</div>';
        }          
    }
    movelist.onscroll = yhandler
});
```

Now your `yhandler` is within the same scope as the place that is using it. In your example,  it was defined an as inner function, and you were trying to access it from outside the function. When you define inner functions, they are like local variables, they can only be access by the function itself.

Comment: Gotcha! My div is not being fired as it is in fiddle still. Thoughts why? @juanMendes